# Kafka streams word count application

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, streaming, apache-kafka-streams

I'm playing around with the kafka streaming API (Kakfa version: 0.10.2.0) trying to make a simple wordcount example work: [Wordcount App gist](https://gist.github.com/ardlema/4f08dc2546881ca994d9f51343e4d79e). I'm running both producer and console consumer:

`./kafka-console-producer.sh -topic input-topic --broker-list localhost:9092`

```
./kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic output-topic --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --from-beginning
```

start the application and everything seems to be working fine but when I type in some strings within the console producer, the consumer receives nothing at all. If I change the app to do a simple toUppercase on the input the consumer receives the stream (modified to upper case) fine:

`//The following code works fine:
val uppercasedWithMapValues: KStream[String, String] = textLines.mapValues(_.toUpperCase())
uppercasedWithMapValues.to("output-topic")`

Does anyone know why I'm receiving nothing on the word-count example? Should I specify any serializer on the consumer? In my last test the console consumer processed the messages that I sent through the console but didn't show them, see below the output:

```
➜  bin ./kafka-console-consumer.sh \
           --topic output-topic \
           --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 \
           --from-beginning                                                                                
[2017-08-02 07:48:20,187]WARN Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 2 : 
{output-topic=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-08-02 07:48:20,197] WARN The following subscribed topics are not assigned 
to any members in the group console-consumer-91651 : [output-topic]  
(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
```

^CProcessed a total of 7 messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`KStream` works because it doesn't use caching. For `KTable` you have to wait a bit, or set `cache.max.bytes.buffering` to `0` (but not in a production code!)

Comment: Awesome! That did the trick! Thank you very much! I guess I need to read more about kafka streams internals. Thank you again @Arek

Comment: I'm glad to help you @ardlema :)