# Kafka Stream Scala API slow performance

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I was exploring Kafka Streams API and implemented sample **WordCountExample** in Scala as well as in Java but when I run the Scala code it gives output very slow  as compared to Java example.

Also I observed that when I produced record on **wordCountInput** topic it appears
instantly in **sinkWordCount** topic but the result of **wordCount** is not displayed instantly in **wordCountOutput** topic if we run the **Scala** code but if we run the **Java** code then everything works fine and I can see the output in **wordCountOutput** topic instantly.

Java code:

```
public class WordCountExample {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Properties p = new Properties();
            p.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "wordcount-application");
            p.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "192.168.1.93:9092");
            p.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
            p.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());

            StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
            KStream<String, String> textLines = builder.stream("wordCountInput");
            KTable<String, String> wordCounts = textLines
                    .flatMapValues(textLine -> Arrays.asList(textLine.toLowerCase().split("\\+W")))
                    .groupBy((key, word) -> word)
                    .count()
                    .mapValues((key, value) -> value.toString());

            textLines.to("sinkWordCount");

            wordCounts.toStream().to("wordCountOutput");

            KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), p);
            streams.cleanUp();
            streams.start();

            Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
                streams.close();
            }));
        }
}
```

POM File of java program

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>KafkaStreamExample</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Scala code :

```
object KafkaStreamExample extends App {

  val props: Properties = {
    val p = new Properties()
    p.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "wordcount-application")
    p.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "192.168.1.93:9092")
    p.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String.getClass)
    p.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String.getClass)
    p
  }
  val builder: StreamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder()
  val sourceStream: KStream[String, String] = builder.stream[String, String]("wordCountInput")

  val wordCounts: KTable[String, String] = sourceStream
    .flatMapValues(textLine => textLine.toLowerCase.split("\\W+"))
    .groupBy((key, word) => word)
    .count()
    .mapValues((key, value) => value.toString)

  wordCounts.toStream.to("wordCountOutput")

  sourceStream.to("sinkWordCount")

  val stream: KafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), props)

  sys.ShutdownHookThread {
    stream.close()
  }

  stream.cleanUp()
  stream.start()
}
```

Scala SBT :

```
name := "KafkaStreamExample"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.6"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka-streams-scala" % "2.0.0"
libraryDependencies += "javax.ws.rs" % "javax.ws.rs-api" % "2.1" artifacts( Artifact("javax.ws.rs-api", "jar", "jar"))
```

Kafka Version: `kafka_2.11-2.0.0`

so can any one tell me why is the scala example is not executing as fast as java example.

**Update**

Setting `cache.max.bytes.buffering` this property to 0 in Scala code gives the instant output of WordCount in Scala but this is not recommended to use in production  according to this [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45452685/kafka-streams-word-count-application)
also in java code we don't need to set this property but still the java give the fast output

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but have you tried using localhost instead? In other words, that extra network hop for an external address might slow something down

Comment: At runtime, everything is executed as Java code. The Scala API is just a thin language wrapper that is used to express the computation. For example, your `flatMapValues()` function is translated into a `ValueMapper` implementation -- from my understanding (not an expert in Scala/Java interoperability), if Scala implements a Java interface, it's the same as you would implement the interface in Java. Thus, no idea why you see different runtime behavior.

Comment: @cricket_007 yes i tried with localhost too but the observation was same

Comment: It would help if your code was the exact same. That's my main point. For example, `split("\\W+")` vs `split(" ")`

Comment: @cricket_007 I was experimenting with scala code to solve the issue and didn't remembered to revert the code same as java before posting it here i will make edit to it

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax have you tried executing my example?